# Adding elements to the std::queue while initializing it

Tags: c++

How can i add elements to the below `std::queue` while initializing it.

```
std::unique_ptr<std::queue<std::unique_ptr<std::string>>> _queue
```

I have tried as follows but it doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <memory>
#include <string> 

int main() {
    // Create a unique pointer to a queue of unique pointers to strings
    std::unique_ptr<std::queue<std::unique_ptr<std::string>>> _queue =
        std::make_unique<std::queue<std::unique_ptr<std::string>>>(
            std::queue<std::unique_ptr<std::string>>(std::make_unique<std::string>("Hello"))
        );
    return 0;
}
```

**Error**

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:10:92: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::queue > >::queue(std::_MakeUniq >::__single_object)’
   10 |             std::queue<std::unique_ptr<std::string>>(std::make_unique<std::string>("Hello"))
      |                                                                                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/queue:64,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_queue.h:195:9: note: candidate: ‘template std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::queue(std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>&&, const _Alloc&) [with _Alloc = _Alloc; _Requires = _Requires; _Tp = std::unique_ptr >; _Sequence = std::deque >, std::allocator > > >]’
  195 |         queue(queue&& __q, const _Alloc& __a)
      |         ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_queue.h:195:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:10:92: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
   10 |             std::queue<std::unique_ptr<std::string>>(std::make_unique<std::string>("Hello"))
      |                                                                                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/queue:64,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_queue.h:191:9: note: candidate: ‘template std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::queue(const std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>&, const _Alloc&) [with _Alloc = _Alloc; _Requires = _Requires; _Tp = std::unique_ptr >; _Sequence = std::deque >, std::allocator > > >]’
  191 |         queue(const queue& __q, const _Alloc& __a)
      |         ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_queue.h:191:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:10:92: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
   10 |             std::queue<std::unique_ptr<std::string>>(std::make_unique<std::string>("Hello"))
      |                                                                                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/queue:64,
```

Comment: OK, you are trying to construct a queue from unique_ptr, and this constructor ofc does not exist. You can do `std::queue<std::unique_ptr<std::string>>({std::make_unique<std::string>("Hello")})` which will construct it from initialiser list, end then you will find another issue - about unique_ptr being non-copyable.

Comment: @pptaszni not working =>     std::unique_ptr<std::queue<std::unique_ptr<std::string>>> _queue =
        std::make_unique<std::queue<std::unique_ptr<std::string>>>(
            std::queue<std::unique_ptr<std::string>>({std::make_unique<std::string>("Hello")})
        );

Comment: @pptaszni so it is not possible?

Comment: Nope. The reason is that the element type is move-only.

Comment: Actually, the [deque docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) says that the only requirement on the type is Erasable. In this [example](https://godbolt.org/z/MvvohjETv) you can see it's possible to create an empty queue, and then push, access, and pop move-only element. I am not sure why it's not allowed to directly construct the queue with move-only elements.

Comment: Due to the lack of appropriate constructors, I couldn't do better than declaration ```std::queue<std::unique_ptr<std::string>> _queue;``` followed by ```_queue.push(std::make_unique<std::string>("Hello"));```

Comment: What is the benefit of wrapping a queue (or any other container) by a unique pointer? A unique pointer provides automatic clean-up, but this provide any container as well. You can pass around unique pointers by moving them, be the same you can do with containers themselves. And, a unique pointer does not guarantee that someone won't be using the pointed-to container directly.

Comment: Why can't you use `std::queue<std::string>`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `std::queue` [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/queue) accepting a `std::unique_ptr`, nor can the latter be copied, only moved.

A possible alternative is to write an helper function, like in the following snippet:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <memory>

template <class T, class ... Ts>
auto make_unique_queue_of_unique(Ts&& ... args)
{
    std::queue<std::unique_ptr<T>> q_;
    (q_.push(std::make_unique<T>(std::move(args))), ...);
    return std::make_unique<decltype(q_)>(std::move(q_));
}

int main()
{ 
    auto uq {make_unique_queue_of_unique<std::string>(
        "Hello", " ",  "World", "!\n"
    )};

    while ( not uq->empty() )
    {
        std::cout << *uq->front();
        uq->pop();
    }
    
    // But why on earth aren't you just writing this:
    std::queue<std::string> q{ {"Hello", " ", "again", "...\n"} };
    
    while ( not q.empty() )
    {
        std::cout << q.front();
        q.pop();
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xxdcn55YT)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there ought to be a simple solution for this, and there *almost* is, but curiously, the C++ library was missing a class we need until C++23: [`std::ranges::as_rvalue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/as_rvalue_view)

```
using QueueType = std::queue<std::unique_ptr<std::string>>;
using std::ranges;
auto inner_ptr = std::make_unique<std::string>("Hello");
auto move_from_set = as_rvalue(views::single(inner_ptr));
std::unique_ptr<QueueType> _queue = std::make_unique<QueueType>(move_from_set);
return 0;
```

Presumably you don't have C++23, but it's probably pretty straightforward to implement `as_rvalue` yourself.

As noted in the comments though, usually a pointer to a container is completely unnecessary.  And `queue` and `string` are both containers. So the usual solution is simply

```
using std::ranges;
std::queue<std::string> _queue = as_rvalue(views::single(std::string("Hello")));
```